# Angular template use non-html language

Tags: angularjs

I am using express server and angular client. I use jade to write express template and the code is very clean.

for example, in index.jade

```
html
  head
    title!= title
  body
    h1!= message
```

Then I can just compile the jade file into html file

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!'});
});
```

Now I am moving some logic to the client to prevent page loading. The drawback is that angular template is as verbose as normal html code. Files get long and messy soon.

For example, in my profile template, I have this

```
        <div class="my-panel-body">
            <table class="my-table">

                <!--email-->
                <tr>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <td>{{entity.email}}</td>
                </tr>

                <!--gender-->
                <tr>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <td>{{entity.meta.gender}}</td>
                </tr>

                <!--dob-->
                <tr>
                    <th>Date of Birth</th>
                    <td>{{entity.meta.dob}}</td>
                </tr>

                <!--country-->
                <tr>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <td>{{entity.meta.country}}</td>
                </tr>

                <!--city-->
                <tr>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <td>{{entity.meta.city}}</td>
                </tr>

                <!--status-->
                <tr>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <td>{{entity.meta.status}}</td>
                </tr>
```

It would be great if I can write things like

```
div
    table
         head
            tr 
               th Date of Birth
               td {{entity.dob}} 
            tr 
               th Email
               td {{entity.email}}
```

It doesn't have to be jade. I am ok with any language as long as its clean and short

Comment: Have you tried this? Are you getting some sort of error?

Comment: have you tested the example you posted? why wouldn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jade runs on the server and Angular runs on the client. When Angular requests the template, it will ask the server and the server will process the Jade template and respond with the generated HTML which is then a valid Angular template.

As long as you're not using any kind of pre-processor to package the Angular templates into a single file, then using Jade on the server to generate Angular templates for the client works fine. If you are using a pre-processor, then you need to run Jade first (which is also possible--Jade is not tied to Express).

Not necessarily related to this question, but it's also useful to note that Angular is not tied to HTML. Any tag based language that the browser supports will work with Angular--SVG, VRML, MathML, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is write them how you want and then before angular loads create a module called templates that uses `$templateCache`. You can put them in there once they're parsed: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

If you need it rendered on the fly you'll have to modifiy how `$http.get` works in your `.config` and check to see if it's a template and if it is pass it through your renderer.

Comment: Why does he need to do any of this? Angular will request the template from the web server, if the web server does the conversion from Jade to HTML, then Angular won't even know the difference.

Comment: Depends if they want to compile the template server side or client side.

Comment: He said in the question he's compiling the Jade template server side. "I use jade to write express template."